# Trying to install dyplr with R version 3.2.0

Tags: r

I'm running version R 3.2.0 through RStudio on my laptop. I am running Windows 8 and I get the following Warning message:

```
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘dyplr’ is not available (for R version 3.2.0)
```

Is there a workaround?  I did install the devtools as suggested in the README file using:

---

```
install.packages("devtools")
devtools::install_github("hadley/lazyeval")
devtools::install_github("hadley/dplyr")
```

This did not appear to help.

Note I did succeed in installing tidyr.

Thank you for any suggestions.

Comment: What's "dyplr"? Is it a typo for "dplyr"?

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo that i carried over into this request. It is dplyr and I think i found the answer to my question.  It appears that when installing the dplyr package it is necessary to call to libraries rather that just he dplyr library as follows:

Comment: Oops, new to stack overflow so acidently dumpted my post before finishing it.  the soluition I found is to do the following:  install.packages("dyplr")
library(Lahman)
library(dplyr)  Why opening the Lahman library works I do not know but it solved my problem.

Comment: Maybe because it is `install.packages("dplyr") `, not "dyplr" .

Comment: You don't need `Lahman` package. Whaveter you did, this isn't the actual solution to your problem (it was likely the typo).

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but I just experienced the same problem with dplyr package installation. It seems that you should consider the dependencies to be installed together, Lahman being one of those. making:

```
install.packages("dplyr", dependencies = TRUE)
```

will solve any eventual problems, I guess.